# How to find a small disk where an analytic function $f(z)$ such that $f(0)=1$ does not have zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:** Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function in $D_R=\left\{z:|z|<R \right\}$ such that $|f(z)|<M \,\, \forall z \in D_R$ and $f(0)=1$. Please find $\rho \in (0,R)$ such that $f(z)$ has no zeros for any $z$ with $|z|\le \rho$

**My thoughts:** This is a past exam problem. I suppose I should try to estimate the growth rate of $|f|$, but I meet a lot of difficulty since the information provided is very limited. I guess the answers should be related to $M$ (otherwise it is not necessary to emphasize $|f|$ is bounded), but I do not know what kind of information is implied when we know this upper bound. I have only taken one elementary course in complex variables so maybe there is some important theorems that I'm missing. Thanks for any comments and answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $g(z)=f(z)-1$. Then $|g(z)|<M+1$ on the disc, and it suffices
to find $\rho>0$ such that $|g(z)|<1$ for $\rho>0$. Let $0<R'<R$
(say $R'=R/2$ if you like). Then $h(z)=g(z)/z$ is holomorphic, and
by maximal modulus theorem, $|h(z)|\le (M+1)/R'$ for $|z|\le R'$.
Therefore $g(z)\le(M+1)|z|/R'$ for $|z|\le R'$. Now take $\rho$
with $0<\rho<R'$ and $(M+1)\rho/R'<1$.